# ENVI 5.1 Help with clipping irregular shapes

Tags: envi, clip

Does anyone know how to clip files using an irregular shapefile so that I don´t get the rectangle geometry in the end?

Answer (score 1):

In ENVI, You can not do this using spatial subset ( i mean subset by non rectangular shapes). As the documentation says that  ENVI generates minimum rectangle for ROI or EVF by which one subsets images.Here you can set background value (for area outside of ROI/EVF) as you want (say 0, 255 etc.) instead.

For details have a look at [here](http://exelisvis.com/Support/Forums/tabid/184/forumid/6/threadid/13473/)

But using mask you can do it in  ENVI as below:
[image: demo]

But for this you need to import shapefile into envi and convert it into evf/roi